# Does every connected compact boundaryless manifold with a point removed have a deformation-retract to a CW complex of one lower dimension?

Tags: manifolds, cw-complexes

Let $M$ be a connected, compact, boundaryless topological manifold of dimension $n$. Let $X$ be the space obtained by removing some point from $M$.

My question is, does $X$ admit a deformation-retract onto a CW complex of dimension $n-1$?

---

I can see directly why this is true for $n=2$, i.e. for $M$ a surface; then we know $M$ can be obtained by taking some plane polygon and identifying pairs of sides; so if we remove a point from the interior, this deformation-retracts to the 1-dimensional CW complex obtained by identifying the pairs of edges (as the sides in the original polygon) and discarding the interior of the polygon.

However, I'm not sure how to generalize this argument to $n>2$. Would anyone know how to proceed in this case?

Comment: In the smooth case, the answer is yes. In general, it is also true that any open $n$-manifold is homotopy-equivalent to an $n-1$-dimensional CW complex, but I don't know about deformation-retracting.

Comment: @Thorgott I see, thank you! For the smooth case, would you know of a reference that explains this?

Comment: [This is one.](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/NoncompactSurfaceFree.pdf)